# JavaScript regular expression check number only

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regular expression for the following values:

```
1) .1 = False.
2) 0.1 = True.
3) 1.1245 = True.
4) 1.2. = False.
5) 1.24.35 = False.
6) 21.152 = true.
```

This regex should check that the string represents an integer or is composed of only numbers and a single `.` representing a decimal point.

I am using: `/^[\+\-]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[Ee][\+\-]?\d+)?$/` but it takes `"1.2."` as `true`.

Comment: You should post what regex you have tried that did not work.

Comment: `/^[\+\-]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[Ee][\+\-]?\d+)?$/.test('1.2.')` returns `false`, not `true`. Cannot reproduce what you are saying.

Comment: @trincot when I enter 1.2. in text box  and print in console.log it shows true, but when I use 1.2.1 then it showing false. I want 1.2. should show false.

Comment: If you are open to other solutions and not restricted to just a regular expression, I'd suggest `Number(x) === Number(x)`; when NaN, it will return false because `NaN === NaN` always returns false.

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin could you please demonstrate with any example.

Comment: *"When I enter 1.2. in text box and print in console.log"* : where is that text box, and where is that `console.log` in your question? Apparently you have code that you have not shared. I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have given.

Comment: use `\d+` not `\d*`, also you don't need to escape here: `[\+\-]` can be `[+-]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking the first digits set as none or more `\d*`, you should use `\d+`, then it would work for the cases you want.

Can also look [here](https://regex101.com/r/yXw3yB/2)

Edit: `^[\+\-]?\d+(\.?\d+(?:[Ee][\+\-]?\d+)?)?$`

Comment: when I enter single digit then it display false.

Comment: Its unstable it is not working for other like "012.5.".

Comment: "012.5." should return false or?

Comment: Yes it is working fine in https://regex101.com/r/yXw3yB/1/ but when I am using like below it return true for "1.2.".


        var reg =  /^[\+\-]?\d+(\.?\d+(?:[Ee][\+\-]?\d+)?)?$/

 console.log(reg.test((edValue.value)));

Comment: I want only one dot enter in the string. if you put second dot it should be false.

Comment: If the regex is working, it should also work with your code. I don't know what `edValue.value` is, and why you use double braces around it. Share your code for it, maybe we find a solution for it as well.

Comment: function edValueKeyPress(event)
    {
        var edValue = document.getElementById("number");
        var data = edValue.value;
  
  var reg =  /^[\+\-]?\d+(\.?\d+(?:[Ee][\+\-]?\d+)?)?$/
  
  console.log(reg.test(data));
    }

Comment: You should better open a new question for it. It is not easy to ready it like so. If you can give a link in that question to an example of your code, would be even better :)

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hg22533j/) if you try to input "15.2." the first alert would still show you "15.2" because of the input attribute `type="number"`. If you change the input type to `text` you will see it works as you would expect it to.

Comment: Great man you are genius. This is exactly same what I want. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems more complex than it needs to be. In order to live up to your requirements (starts with a number, ends with a number, at most one dot) you can use the following:

```
(^\d+\.\d+$)|(^\d+$)
```

Edit:
Or even simpler:

```
^\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

Comment: When I use "12.2." it returns true, if I changes with "12.2.3" then its working file. I want it should show false when I use "12.2.".

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior. Are you sure that the error isn't in the surrounding code?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following regex

> (?:\d*.)?\d+

It will match only real numbers.

If the input is like `1.2.3` it will return `1.2`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

you were puting the dot in the wrong place this should work

```
[\+\-]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+(?:[Ee][\+\-]?[0-9]+)?)?
```